# restart countdown timer to every next friday

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer, countdown

I need to restart my countdown timer every next friday, i cant seem to get it done. this is my code
 this is my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/9L7f5s6u/

```js
var countDownDate = new Date("Mar 10, 2017 17:00:00").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

var now = new Date().getTime();

var distance = countDownDate - now;

var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)).toString();
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 *      60)).toString();
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)).toString();
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000).toString();

document.getElementById("circle-days").innerHTML = days + "<div class='timer-font'>Días</div>";
document.getElementById("circle-hours").innerHTML = hours + "<div class='timer-font'>Hrs</div>";
document.getElementById("circle-minutes").innerHTML = minutes + "<div class='timer-font'>Min</div>";
document.getElementById("circle-seconds").innerHTML = seconds + "<div class='timer-font'>Seg</div>";

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<span style="margin-right: 10px;">
      <span id="circle-days" class="circle-time"></span>
    </span>
    <span style="margin-right: 10px;">
      <span id="circle-hours" class="circle-time"></span>
    </span>
    <span style="margin-right: 10px;">
      <span id="circle-minutes" class="circle-time"></span>
    </span>
    <span id="circle-seconds" class="circle-time"></span>
  <span id="timer"></span>
```

Comment: you just need to reset counter on next friday or you need the counter to show time remaining from the day website hit till friday inot dd hr mm ss format?

Answer (score 0):

See  https://jsfiddle.net/9L7f5s6u/2/ using a function that returns the next day of week (in this case 5/Friday and 17 as hour)

```
function getNextDayOfWeek(date, dayOfWeek, hour) {
      var resultDate = new Date(date.getTime());
    resultDate.setDate(date.getDate() + (7 + dayOfWeek - date.getDay()) % 7);
    resultDate.setHours(hour,0,0,0);
    return resultDate;
}
```

Code based from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33527/find-next-occurring-friday-or-any-dayofweek adding a start hour.

Answer (score 0):

You could go over the top and use something like [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) and add a week to your `countDownDate`.

Or you can do something like

```
countDownDate = new Date(countDownDate.valueOf() + 604800000);
```

All this snippet does is gets the time in ms from 1/1/1970 and adds 1 week in ms to that time and creates a new date object one week ahead of the countDownDate.

This is all assuming that `countDownDate` is a Friday.

As for resetting the timer, I believe that the code shouldn't be too hard to continue from there

Answer (score 0):

I'll do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/hdLz5rux/

```
countDownDate.setDate(countDownDate.getDate() + 7);
```